# WPF Usercontrol doesn't always follows the mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set up a usercontrol position so that it follows the mouse. Precisely, the mouse needs to be in the center of the empty block of my grid (150 pixel away from the top left corner)

```
    private void MoveTrackpad(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Point point = System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition;
        trackpad.MoveTo(point.X, point.Y);
    }

  public void MoveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        this.Left = x - 150;
        this.Top = y - 150;
    }
```

The problem that i face is that it doesn't work on my [computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXnCE.jpg) . But it works when i use a [external screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALm3T.jpg). I changed nothing in the code between the 2 pictures.

On my computer, the trackpad and mouse are correctly aligned in the top-left corner of the screen. The farther i get from that point, more they are distant from each other

Sorry for the bad quality, but i took a picture instead of a screenshot to show the mouse position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are using a WinForms API for the mouse position which doesn't handle screen DPI and WPF's metrics.

Try using `Mouse.GetPosition(...)` instead.